# Como Imprimir elementos de un ArrayList

Tags: java

La opcion 2 solo imprime los primeros 2 datos ingresados y necesito poder imprimir los datos ingresados para las otras personas en el caso que ingrese mas de 1 persona.
**Main class**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package colecciones;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 *
 * @author mmt
 */
public class Colecciones {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int opcion = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Persona>listadoPersona = new ArrayList();
        do {
        System.out.println("1)Ingresar Persona");
        System.out.println("2)Ver Persona");
        System.out.println("3)Consultar si la persona existe");
        System.out.println("4)Salir");
        System.out.printf("Ingrese una opcion: ");
        opcion = sc.nextInt();
        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                System.out.printf("Ingrese la cantidad de Personas a crear: ");
                int cantidad = sc.nextInt();
                for(int i = 1;i <= cantidad; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre de la Persona Nº " + i);
                    String nombre = sc.next();
                    System.out.println("Ingrese edad de la Persona Nº " + i);
                    int edad = sc.nextInt();
                    Persona persona = new Persona(nombre,edad);
                    listadoPersona.add(persona);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                for(Persona n : listadoPersona) {
                    System.out.println("+---------------------+");
                    System.out.println("Nombre: " + n.getNombre());
                    System.out.println("Edad: " + n.getEdad());
                    System.out.println("+---------------------+");
                break;
                }
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                System.exit(1);
                break;
            }
        } while(opcion != 3);
    }    
}
```

**Clase Persona**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package colecciones;

/**
 *
 * @author mmt
 */
public class Persona {
    private String nombre;
    private int edad;
    public Persona(String nombre, int edad) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }
}
```

**Output** 
run: 
1)Ingresar Persona 
2)Ver Persona 
3)Consultar si la persona existe
4)Salir
Ingrese una opcion: 1

Ingrese la cantidad de Personas a crear: 2
Ingrese el nombre de la Persona Nº 1
Juan
Ingrese edad de la Persona Nº 1
23
Ingrese el nombre de la Persona Nº 2
Pedro
Ingrese edad de la Persona Nº 2
34
1)Ingresar Persona 
2)Ver Persona
3)Consultar si la persona existe
4)Salir
Ingrese una opcion: 2
+---------------------+
Nombre: Juan
Edad: 23
+---------------------+

La opcion 2 solo imprime los primeros 2 datos ingresados como puedo imprimir los datos ingresados para las otras personas en el caso que ingrese mas de 1 persona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el case 2 tienes el break dentro del ciclo for, por eso es que cuando acaba la primera iteracion ahora usa el break para salir del for y salir del case. Esa es la razon por la cual no alcanza a imprimir la siguiente persona.

```
        case 2:
            for(Persona n : listadoPersona) {
                System.out.println("+---------------------+");
                System.out.println("Nombre: " + n.getNombre());
                System.out.println("Edad: " + n.getEdad());
                System.out.println("+---------------------+");
            break;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes trabajarlo como un conjunto:`Persona[] listadoPersona =null;` ,donde cada indice es un: `new Persona()`, así tendrás n cantidades alamacenadas: `listadoPersona =new Persona[cantidad];` al momento de elegir la segunda opción, pruebalo:

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
    int opcion = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

     Persona[] listadoPersona =null;
    do {
    System.out.println("1)Ingresar Persona");
    System.out.println("2)Ver Persona");
    System.out.println("3)Consultar si la persona existe");
    System.out.println("4)Salir");
    System.out.printf("Ingrese una opcion: ");
    opcion = sc.nextInt();
    switch (opcion) {
        case 1:
            System.out.printf("Ingrese la cantidad de Personas a crear: ");
            int cantidad = sc.nextInt();
                listadoPersona =new Persona[cantidad];
            for(int i = 1;i <= cantidad; i++) {
                System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre de la Persona Nº " + i);
                String nombre = sc.next();
                System.out.println("Ingrese edad de la Persona Nº " + i);
                int edad = sc.nextInt();
               listadoPersona[i-1]  = new Persona(nombre,edad);



            }
            break;
        case 2:
            for(int e=0;e<listadoPersona.length;e++){

                System.out.println("+---------------------+");
                System.out.println("Nombre: " + listadoPersona[e].getNombre());
                System.out.println("Edad: " + listadoPersona[e].getEdad());
                System.out.println("+---------------------+");

            }
            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        case 4:
            System.exit(1);
            break;
        }
    } while(opcion != 3);


}
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda